# is it possible to have two RecyclerViews on top of each other and make them both clickable?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**My XML file:** recyclerViewOverlay is to have empty image frames. recyclerView holds the actual images.
[image]

**Emulator screenshot:**

[image]

**My problem:** When I add an actual image in the recycleView e.g. in position 0 I set the recyclerViewOverlay position 0 to view.GONE, however, I still cannot click on position 0 that is in the recyclerView even though I am setting the position of recycrlerViewOverlay to GONE like this:

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerViewOverlay.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0);
View view = viewHolder.itemView;
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put 2 `RecyclerView`'s on top of each other. Instead set placeholder and actual images in `onBindViewHolder()` in your `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Note: In order to use placeholders you need to know the number of images upfront.